# How do I retrieve a score from a leaderboard in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I want to display the highest scores of a `GKPlayer` with a `GKLeaderboard` in Swift.

```
func login() {

if (GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated) {

        var leaderboardRequest: GKLeaderboard!
        leaderboardRequest.identifier = "Best_Score"

        // Error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        func loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: (([AnyObject]!,
            NSError!) -> Void)!) {

             var localPlayerScore: GKScore = leaderboardRequest.localPlayerScore
        }
    }
}
```

Though, `func loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler` returns this error message: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` because I'm forcing unwrapping an Optional that contains nil.

Where's the error with my code?

Comment: Is it _normal_ that you declare a function inside your if statement ?

Comment: I think declaring isn't _normal_. What you want is to use it, as _blacksquare_ showed you below (class method).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're declaring `GKLeaderboard`, but not initializing it. Note also that `loadLeaderboardWithCompletionHandler` is a class function of GKLeaderBoard. Do this instead:

```
if (GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated) {
    GKLeaderboard.loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler { objects, error in
       if let e = error {
           println(e)
       } else {
           if let leaderboards = objects as? [GKLeaderboard] {
               for leaderboard in leaderboards {
                   if let localPlayerScore = leaderboard.localPlayerScore {
                        println(localPlayerScore)
                   }
               }
            }
       }
   }
}
```

As a sidenote, it's not safe to use implicitly unwrapped optionals, i.e., anything declared with a `!`. Take for example your program here: you can compile it and have to dig through your code to find where the runtime error actually occurred. If you would have declared `var leaderBoardRequest: GKLeaderBoard?`, you would have been able to identify the source of your problem immediately without having to compile and run.

Comment: Thank you! What would I insert inside `params`?

Comment: I have been able to identify the source of my problem using breakpoints. In fact, the problem occurs when this code is executed: `func loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler`. Thanks again for your help. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Well thats one among several of the issues here. I just looked at the documentation for GKLeaderboard, look at my amended response

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. Unfortunately, the code in your answer crashes my app. I used a breakpoint and I detected that once the complier has gone through `GKLeaderboard.loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler ` found `nil` while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer again! I appreciate you taking time helping me through this issue. The issue still persists, even when using the new code. I placed a breakpoint in `GKLeaderboard.loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler { objects, error in` and I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I can't do much more to check what's going on without looking at the actual code--do you have a git project I can look at?

Comment: My bad. It wasn't the function to give the error, but these two lines of code: `var leaderboardRequest: GKLeaderboard!
                    leaderboardRequest.identifier = "Best_Score"`. As you mentioned in your answer, there may be a issue with them.

Comment: yep--you have to scrap those two lines--it's not initialized

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't created a Git project yet. Could you please help me scraping `var leaderboardRequest: GKLeaderboard!`? Removing `!` won't do much because it's necessary, isn't it? I mean, if the user is being logged there is no reason the leaderboard should not exist.

Comment: just get rid of those two lines altogether. Replace the whole block of code you have up there with my answer and run it.

Comment: I am still getting the pesky error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Well, that's a kinda reasonable error this time because the compiler doesn't know which leaderboard it should show, doesn't it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72004/discussion-between-blacksquare-and-cecexx).